# Display Image downloaded from downloadURL generated by Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to display the images that have been stored on the storage on Firebase. Right now, I only tracked the images using the link generated by function `downloadURL`:

```
    func UploadImage(imageData: Data, path: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> ()){
        
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        
        storage.child(path).child(uid ?? "").putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (_, err) in
            
            if err != nil{
                completion("")
                return
                
            }
            // Downloading Url And Sending Back...
            storage.child(path).child(uid ?? "").downloadURL { (url, err) in
                if err != nil{
                    completion("")
                    return
                    
                }
                completion("\(url!)")
            }
        }
    }
```

So all I can get is a hyperlink that is like: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/getting-started-20f2f.appspot.com/o/profile_Photos%2FGQ1KR9H1mLZl2NAw9KQcRe7d72N2?alt=media&token=473ce86c-52ba-42ec-be71-32cc7dc895d7`.
I refer to the official documentation, it seems that only when I have the name of the image file can I download it to an ImageView or UIImageView object. However, the link does not make any sense to me, so what can I do?

**EDIT**

I actually tried a solution provided by the official documentation:

```
func imageDownloader(_ imageURL: String) {
        let store = Database.database().reference()
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let imageRef = store.child(imageURL)
        var myImageView = UIImageView()

        imageRef.getData(completion: { (error, data) in
            if let error = error {
              // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            } else {
              // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
              let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
          })
    }
```

But it suggests that I need to change something because `Cannot convert value of type 'DataSnapshot' to expected argument type 'Data'`.

Comment: That's not the error I would expect to see... but, it looks like you've reversed the callback parameters -- the documentation shows `data, error in`

Comment: No, if I did it as the doc tells us, it will be worse. This is because the order of error and data has been designed in the `getData()`. I just had no idea why Google could make such a mistake.

Comment: Ah -- I see the issue now. You're trying to call it on `Database`, which is the realtime database. You should be calling it on `Storage.storage()`

Comment: Ahh, that's a good catch! Let me try!

Comment: You appear to be having an issue with `path` as that should be the path to the image, including the image name, like this `let riversRef = storageRef.child("images/rivers.jpg")`. Once that's been uploaded, get the full url from within the closure following the putData call and store that full url in the database. e.g. if you're uploading code doesn't work, then downloading won't work either. Check your `path` var in the upload function and see if it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're storing the image paths in Firestore, actually the exact file name does not matter if there is only one file available under the fork. So you just need to specify the path.

To then download the image from Storage, construct the path and download:

```
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

Storage.storage().reference().child("the\path\to\your\uid\collection").child(uid).getData(maxSize: 1048576, completion: { (data, error) in
    if let data = data,
       let img = UIImage(data: data) {
        // do something with your image
    } else {
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        // handle errors
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are uploading to `Storage.storage()`, but then in your `imageDownloader`, you're attempting to use `Database.database()`, which has a similar-looking API, but is, in fact, different.

Make sure to use `Storage.storage()` and that the closure parameters are in the order `data, error in`.

Finally, right now in your `imageDownloader`, it doesn't look like you're doing anything yet with `var myImageView = UIImageView()`, but keep in mind that you won't have access to the `UIImage` until the async `getData` completes.

Comment: I modified and tried this method. It doesn't work, because no object was found. Perhaps I really need to change the way how an image is stored.

Comment: Check in Firebase console and see if there’s really something there

Comment: Of couse there is, you can even copy it and try to download it on your own.

Comment: And you’re sure the paths are identical?

Comment: Well if you tried it now, it could not work because I uploaded another image so the URL was changed/

Comment: I’m not concerned with whether the URL has something there — I’m wondering if there is something at the exact path that you’re specifying in the download method.

Comment: Well, I think I got you. I tried `fullPath()` instead of `child()`, however, it said that `Cannot call value of non-function type 'String'`. Do you have any ideas why it is that?

Comment: Sorry — I don’t know what you’re trying to do there. I just mean that if you’re looking for “user/image/profile.png” that there is actually something at that location. The first error you describe suggests that that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

Store your images at Firebase Storage & then retrieve using this code.

```
Storage.storage().reference.child("ProfilePhotos").child("ImageName").downloadURL {(url, _) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let url = url else { return }
                imageView.setImage(with: url, placeholder: UIImage(named: "dummyImage"))
            }
        }
```